# Load distributed data from muliple databases in one get request with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing an REST backend api for loading sensor data. The data is stored in following structure:

```
 - data_2019_11
  - data_100403
  - data_100405
  - ...
 - data_2019_12
  - data_100403
  - data_100405
  - ...
 - data_2020_01
  - data_100403
  - data_100405
  - ...
```

I have a MySQL database for each month (e.g. 2019_11), within every database, I have a table for each sensor (e.g. with the sensor id 100403) which contains then the actual data.

Assuming, that I want to load the data of a specific sensor from a certain timestamp to another, which can be a period over several months. How could I realize that?

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: `data_2019_11` is different database or schema? Assuming this is Relational Database what is the database vendor(e.g. PostgreSql, MySql etc) ?

Comment: The vendor is MySQL

Comment: Is the data stored in different databases or schema

Comment: In different databases